# RingCT missing output indices

Tags: blockchain, security, protocol

I'm currently studying about security about Monero, and I found something weird.

I know that the ouputs of Monero transactions are identified by *amount and indices* (amount 0 for RingCT), and the transactions are using this format.

I recently checked that "*6f6f2eea2e549a69ad10246511ccc720193f1d41c9fa2c7aae0e47cb9884d898*" transaction with *1,220,517* height of block is the first RingCT transaction in Monero. However, the blockchain data is showing that the output indices of the transaction is [not starting with 0 index](https://xmrchain.net/tx/6f6f2eea2e549a69ad10246511ccc720193f1d41c9fa2c7aae0e47cb9884d898), rather starting with the index of 2. It seems to be no index 0 output within RingCT transactions.

[image]

Furthermore, I found that other transaction is using the 0 index of RingCT output as a mix-in in an input. I wonder what the situation is and what I am missing is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From v4 at height 1,220,516, where rct becomes allowed, coinbase outputs are stored as pseudo rct outputs. There is one such output in block 1,220,516 and one in 1,220,517.

Comment: If than, I just wonder why blockchain data is not storing them with a pseudo outputs? It seems doing that way would be more clear and easy. Does the version 2 coinbase transactions can be used as inputs of RingCT and non-RingCT, and thus using pseudo indices and real indices for each, respectively?

Comment: They can only be used as inputs to rct txes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask you some related document if exists? or Do I have to see the code?

Comment: Can't think of anything beyond code.